# Extract only first element of tuple

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a column on my data containing a list of two elements of tuples from POS tagging. I want to extract only the first element of these tuples and append it to another column. All code I found can only be applied to a single list of tuples. I would like to loop the code for every row as I have more than 100 rows.

| pos_tag_clean | word_clean |
| --- | --- |
| [(semoga, SC), (saja, RB), (di, IN), (sini, PR), (bisa, MD), (cepat, JJ), (cair, NN), (semoga, NN), (saja, RB), (ini, PR), (beneran, NN), (ada, VB), (nya, NN), (bantuan, NN), (buat, JJ), (butuh, VB), (banget, NN)] | [semoga, saja, di, sini, bisa, cepat, cair, semoga, saja, ini, beneran, ada, nya, bantuan, buat, butuh, banget] |
| [(kak, VB), (kenapa, WH), (perbaikan, NN), (sistem, NN), (nya, PRP), (tidak, NEG), (selesai, VB)] | [kak, kenapa, perbaikan, sistem, nya, tidak, selesai] |
| [(sangat, RB), (baik, JJ)] | [sangat, baik] |

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Is this pandas? If so, please add a tag for it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add reproducible data

Comment: This should be easy considering each of the rows are stored as lists. Looping inside the list will give you access to each tuple. And then according to the row index that you are on you should be able to rewrite to the column of word_clean near it. So this will be a nested loop where you first read the column and inside the column you read the tuple and append the first of value to a new list and write that list on the word_clean column. At each first loop you have to empty the list too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if each row is stored in pos_tag_clean, you could do a list comprehension:

```
word_clean = [[item[0] for item in row] for row in pos_tag_clean]
```